# Water based oil modified polyurethane finish beading when applied over stain on pine

Tags: staining, polyurethane

I applied Minwax Wood Finish penetrating stain to white pine cabinet. Wiped stain thoroughly, waited 60 hours before attempting to apply Minwax water based, oil-modified polyurethane, using synthetic bristle brush. All of this is exactly as per instructions on products.

The only thing I did that wasn't on the Minwax instructions was to soak my brush in paint thinner to release trapped air, then wipe on paper until dry before dipping in the polyurethane. This advice was given by several different experts online.

As I drew my brush across the piece, the poly immediately began beading up. I took another stroke through, now beading up through the entire length of the stroke.

I Immediately wiped the poly off and then wiped the area again using solvent. The piece may have lost a tiny bit of colour on that strip, but it looks ok.

What should I do now?

Answer (score 1):

> **water based**, oil-modified polyurethane
>   paint thinner

There's your problem right there. Paint thinner and waterbased finishes don't go together.

> This advice was given by several different experts online.

That's in relation to standard varnishes (oil-based).

Never loading finish — this includes oil, varnish, paint or shellac — into a dry brush is sound practice, but you use the appropriate solvent in each case. With waterbased finishes that's water*.

---

*Usually plain water but some prefer water mixed with a little of an additive, e.g. flow aid or retarder.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  That's what I would have thought, but the advice I read was specific to water-based, oil-modified products... go figure.

Comment: Anyhow, in the meantime, I decided that the most likely culprit had to be residual stain on the surface, despite my previous wiping and what seemed to be a completely dry finish.   Decided to wash down the surface with more of the same paint thinner (Recordsol), let that dry and tried again with the poly.  Tried it first on a test stick,then on the underside of one of the panels from my cabinet.  Still waiting for the 1st coat to dry, but didn't bead as it went on, so I'm hopeful.

Comment: Update:  Just went out to shop to check...its about 2 hours since I applied first coat... surface is dry now and looks good.  Will leave it until tomorrow to make sure before light sanding and second coat application.

Comment: *"the advice I read was specific to water-based, oil-modified products"* That's odd. Can you list a couple of the sources please?

Comment: When I originally searched this subject, it didn't occur to me to save my pages. I just went back through my browsing history, but in the available time, I'm unable to  find the pages I'm referring to...grrr!   My memory says one of them was actually the Minwax site, and I had to mine in down several layers of menus before I got to the one in question, but I just can't find it again.

Comment: But since Minwax wb oil-mod poly is made for use over either water or oil based stain, I guess it's a little different than just wb poly.  Meanwhile, as per my previous comment, after washing the whole project with the same paint thinner to remove any residual stain (even though the stain had been wiped and the wood seemed perfectly dry), drying, applying poly and letting that cure, it was nice and hard. Light sanded with 220 and applied a second coat. Eliminated bubbles by using the featherlite pressure and slow stroke method. Second coat has dried beautifully.

Comment: I'm now debating whether I really have to apply a third coat for a wall cabinet that will only see light use.

Comment: *"But since Minwax wb oil-mod poly is made for use over either water or oil based stain, I guess it's a little different than just wb poly."* Actually, as clarified here in a couple of Answers, regular waterbased products can be successfully used over oil-based products (after they've had sufficient time to cure). However on the flipside, if you read the General Finishes directions for their equivalent to the Minwax stuff (Enduro-Var) it specifically warns against using it over oil-based stain.

Comment: Interesting.  Definitely, in this instance, the instructions on the can recommend the Minwax wb oil mod for over regular Minwax Wood Finish Penetrating stain which is oil based.   The take away being, never take anything for granted... always read the instructions. This experience also demonstrated to me that simply wiping off excess stain to a dry surface was not good enough - a final wipedown with solvent was required in order for this type of poly to adhere.

Comment: That might not be the only thing you can take away here, to begin with how scrupulously the excess stain is removed I'm sure is going to be a big factor. "I wiped the excess off." isn't the same as "I wiped the surface completely dry." (the second being more in line with what users should be doing). And of course there is the issue of dampening the brush with paint thinner and not water.

Comment: As per my initial comment, I wiped the stain THOROUGHLY.   As per my follow up comment, I wiped to what seemed to be a COMPLETELY DRY finish.  It would not have been possible for anyone to make it drier by simply rubbing with dry cloth or paper rags.  I believe that what likely happened is that due to multiple applications of stain due to trying to deepen and even out colour, I may have super saturated the wood beyond its capacity to soak it up, so it kept seeping up. It was necessary to use solvent to pull enough out of the wood to halt the seepage

Comment: There are a lot of products out in the marketplace which are sold with a very simplistic set of instructions...advising that if you just do 1. 2. 3. You will have results like in the picture. If your results aren’t perfect you must have missed a step. Oftentimes this is not quite true...there can be other factors that an expert, having come across before, considers minor and obvious. These are where a beginner is at a disadvantage. I did a lot of research on this project before beginning and came up with some useful stuff, but also a lot of so-called experts just repeating steps 1,2,3...

Comment: ...and advising me that if I didn,t have success I must have ignored one of the basic steps.  So my advice to others is...don,t settle for that kind of advice...keep searching...there ARE better instructions out there for most things.

Comment: *"As per my initial comment, I wiped the stain THOROUGHLY"* No offence intended, but I can't tell you how many times I've read posts saying "I did XXX thoroughly" and then it turns out later it wasn't really. *"There are a lot of products out in the marketplace which are sold with a very simplistic set of instructions..."* Yes that is so true. It is worst with stuff at the cheaper end of the mass market but by no means confined to that sector, plenty of prosumer and pro products with poor instructions (and usually also give an unrealistic idea of product effectiveness).

Comment: Finally, on that thought...the Minwax products that I used turned out beautifully.  Lovely tone, glowing satin finish, completely cured to a strong surface.  Their instructions are sparse however. But the only piece I was really missing was that stain might keep rising after wiping. Note in my initial comment...after wiping dry, I was unable to get back to the project for more than two full days.  I’m thinking that in that time period, there was lots of time for the stain to rise and then kind of set in the surface texture so that it still seemed clean and dry...

Comment: ...when, in fact, it was impregnated with oil. So if I were advising someone with this problem, I would now know to say that if they’ve reapplied stain several times, they should let it sit for a while to give the excess time to rise, then wipe with solvent (even if wood appears to be dry ), and let dry for a few minutes before applying poly.